# Limit CSS file inject to only a website homepage (nothing past the domain)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am creating a simple Chrome extension that blocks the black bar on *only* the [Google homepage](http://www.google.com) using a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). But I do not want it to block the black bar once the user has searched.

That is, I want it to apply to this address:

> http://www.google.com

But not this address:

> http://www.google.com/search-terms-here/

In the manifest.json I have been using this to block the bar:

```
  "content_scripts": [
   {
    "matches": ["http://google.com"],
    "css": ["blocker.css"]
   }
```

But using `"matches": ["http://google.com"]` is not working. Does anyone know what address I should use under `"matches"` to get the desired result?

Comment: There's no "www" in your `matches` clause.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference

Comment: Try changing it to `http://google.com/` and if that doesn't work then you could always add a `"exclude_matches": ["http://google.com/search*"]`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with the manifest alone, you must programmatically inject the CSS.

Reference: [Chrome, "Match patterns and globs"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs)

Several issues, big to small:

- [Chrome still has **a bug** whereby CSS injection ignores `exclude_globs` and `exclude_matches`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106).
- Google makes heavy use of hashtags and query parameters, and `matches` and `exclude_matches` do not work on those.
- Google makes heavy use of AJAX, so "new" pages do not load fresh.  This means that you must be able to switch off whatever CSS you add.
- Google uses `www.`. Your matches must be like: `"http://www.google.com/"`.
- `"http://google.com"` is not valid for `match`.  It will give the error:

> Could not load extension from '{never you mind!}'. Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Empty path.
>
> ---

## Solution:

1. Use classes for your CSS, don't alter the element CSS directly.  This is for ease of switching.
2. Programmatically inject the CSS.
3. Listen for the `hashchange` event to know when to remove the new class(es) from the target elements.

Here's an example extension:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts":  [ {
        "js":               [ "CSS_handler.js" ],
        "matches":          [ "http://www.google.com/", "https://www.google.com/" ],
        "exclude_globs":    [ "http://www.google.com/#*", "https://www.google.com/#*" ]
    } ],
    "name":         "AJAX aware, CSS injection switching",
    "description":  "From SO 17395877.  Inject at home page, not 'results' pages. css property fires incorrectly due to bug. Target pages (Google) load 'new' pages via AJAX.",
    "version":      "1",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["blocker.css"]
}
```

**blocker.css:**

```
.mycsHide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**CSS_handler.js:**

```
var link    = document.createElement ("link");
link.href   = chrome.extension.getURL ("blocker.css");
link.type   = "text/css";
link.rel    = "stylesheet";
document.head.appendChild (link);

//-- Global vars
var cssSelectorsToHide  = [
    "#gbz",
    "#gbx3"
];
var hideElems           = true;


//-- Initial run on cold start or full reload.
fireOnNewPage ();

//-- Run on "new" ajax pages.
window.addEventListener ("hashchange", fireOnNewPage,  false);

function fireOnNewPage () {
    /*-- Only hide if there is no hash or URL params.
        The manifest makes sure there is no path.
    */
    hideElems = ! (location.hash  ||  location.search);

    cssSelectorsToHide.forEach (setElemVisibility);
}

function setElemVisibility (selector) {
    var nodes   = document.querySelectorAll (selector);

    //-- Add or remove our special CSS class...
    for (var J = nodes.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
        if (hideElems) {
            nodes[J].classList.add ("mycsHide");
        }
        else {
            nodes[J].classList.remove ("mycsHide");
        }
    }
}
```